Custom kernel development problem / uppercase characters
I'm trying to create a custom kernel using C.  The keyboard input is working fine, but when I want to write with capital letters, it works (this feature is activated when I click on the left or the right shift), but when I click on the shift key again to write with lower-case, it will not work (still writing with upper-case).
void keyboard_handler_main(void){

    unsigned char status;
    char keycode;

    /* write EOI */

    write_port(0x20, 0x20);
    status = read_port(KEYBOARD_STATUS_PORT);
    /* lowesr bit of status will be set if buffer is not empty */
    
    if(status & 0x1){
        keycode = read_port(KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT);
        if(keycode <0)
            return;

        if(keycode == ENTRY_KEY_CODE){
            kprint_newline();
            return;
        }
        // change the state when the shift is pressed
        if (keycode == 0x2A || keycode == 0x36) {  // Left or Right Shift pressed
            if(shift_pressed)
                shift_pressed = 0;
            else
                shift_pressed = 1;
            vidptr[current_loc++] = '1';  // Debugging output (you can remove this later)
            vidptr[current_loc++] = 0x07;  // Light grey on black background
             return;
        }

This function below is the one that let get the key pressed and print it on the screen.  You should know that char shift_pressed is declared as a global variable and has 0 as initial value .
I tried to change the state of shift_pressed whith this method but didn't work :
if(keycode == 0x2A || keycode == 0x36 ){
    shift_pressed = !(keycode & 0x80);
    vidptr[current_loc++] ='1'; /* the character's  ASCII */
    vidptr[current_loc++] = 0x07; /* attribute byte : light grey black screen */
    return;
} 


Unrelated: please define meaningful const variables for those hard-coded constants. It improves readability and also helps when you want to change the value (you only have to change it at one place).

"You should know that char shift_pressed is declared as a global variable and has 0 as initial value" - Do not describe your code. Instead, post it as is in form of [mcve].

Theses two lines don't make sense: if(keycode == 0x2A || keycode == 0x36 ){     shift_pressed = !(keycode & 0x80);. If the condition is fulfilled, keycode & 0x80 must be 0, so shift_pressed will always be true
